# OpenLayers 3 - GeoJson not rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openlayers-3

I have some problems with OpenLayers 3 to show data from GeoJson.

I create my map like that :

```
this.tile = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    this.map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            this.tile
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([ 5.36978, 43.296482]),
            zoom: 15
        })
    });
```

Everything is ok.
But after I try to print GeoJson data from Javascript object :

```
    var geoJson = this.mapDetailsCOllection.toGeoJSON();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(geoJson));
        var self = this;
        var featuresSource = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJson);
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: featuresSource
        });
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource/*,
            style: function(feature, resolution){
                var type = feature.getProperties().properties.type;
                console.log('ououuoeueroeour');
                return self.generateStyle(type);
            }*/
        });
        this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

And my var geoJson is that :

```
  {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "EPSG:4326"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            5.3545079,
            43.373659
          ],
          [
            5.3544664,
            43.3735782
          ],
          [
            5.3544181,
            43.3735333
          ],
          [
            5.3543444,
            43.3734721
          ],
          [
            5.3541516,
            43.3733643
          ],
          [
            5.3540047,
            43.3733116
          ],
          [
            5.3538005,
            43.3732814
          ],
          [
            5.3528094,
            43.3731833
          ],
          [
            5.3527243,
            43.3731765
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Boulevard Henri Barnier",
        "maxspeed": 50,
        "id": -2038873636,
        "bridge": false,
        "type": 1,
        "oneway": true
      }
    },
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            5.3633132,
            43.3611009
          ],
          [
            5.3632272,
            43.3611809
          ],
          [
            5.3631024,
            43.3613018
          ],
          [
            5.3629833,
            43.3613922
          ],
          [
            5.3629117,
            43.3614416
          ],
          [
            5.3628054,
            43.3615235
          ],
          [
            5.3625412,
            43.3616886
          ],
          [
            5.3623373,
            43.3618346
          ],
          [
            5.3621857,
            43.361967
          ],
          [
            5.3619703,
            43.3622247
          ],
          [
            5.3618464,
            43.3624126
          ],
          [
            5.3618364,
            43.3624269
          ],
          [
            5.3616895,
            43.3626378
          ],
          [
            5.3614701,
            43.3630478
          ],
          [
            5.3613125,
            43.3633716
          ],
          [
            5.3612629,
            43.3634894
          ],
          [
            5.3612086,
            43.3636132
          ],
          [
            5.3611875,
            43.3636623
          ],
          [
            5.361132,
            43.3638182
          ],
          [
            5.3611237,
            43.363843
          ],
          [
            5.361084,
            43.3641241
          ],
          [
            5.361067,
            43.3643252
          ],
          [
            5.3610895,
            43.3643945
          ],
          [
            5.3611068,
            43.364448
          ],
          [
            5.3611903,
            43.3645645
          ],
          [
            5.3613475,
            43.3646955
          ],
          [
            5.3616231,
            43.3648651
          ],
          [
            5.3617917,
            43.3650309
          ],
          [
            5.3619251,
            43.3651891
          ],
          [
            5.3619892,
            43.3653298
          ],
          [
            5.3620224,
            43.3656472
          ],
          [
            5.3620432,
            43.3657719
          ],
          [
            5.362105,
            43.3658554
          ],
          [
            5.3624107,
            43.3660538
          ],
          [
            5.3625926,
            43.366176
          ],
          [
            5.36278,
            43.3663392
          ],
          [
            5.3629792,
            43.3665942
          ],
          [
            5.3629819,
            43.3666446
          ],
          [
            5.3629833,
            43.3666822
          ],
          [
            5.3629868,
            43.3667726
          ],
          [
            5.3629925,
            43.3669209
          ],
          [
            5.3630792,
            43.3674142
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Chemin de Saint-Antoine à Saint-Joseph",
        "maxspeed": 50,
        "id": -1738317992,
        "bridge": false,
        "type": 1,
        "oneway": false
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": "EPSG:3857"
}
```

I realy don't understand... Thank you.

**SOLUTION :**

The problème was the projection, I had to put that :

```
var featuresSource = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJson, {
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
```

Comment: Any error in debugger?

Comment: No error in debugger, but I found the solution. I forgot to put projection :
var featuresSource = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJson, {
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });